# minimum height problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

assume I have a such html order

```
<div id="header">>Header(logo, navigation menus etc)will be here, fixed height </div>

<div id="content"> Dynamic content with different length will be here.  </div>

<div id="footer"> Footer of the page here, fixed height </div>
```

Now as you can see, it is only the content div which will be changing in size as the length changes. I want to make sure the screen is used even if the height of the content is less than to fill the whole. (in other words minimum height of the content will be screen `(height of the screen in pixel) - ( (height of header) + (height of footer) )`

Now I can see that min-widht can be used but it is not supported with IE, how can I achieve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this example that anchors the footer to the bottom of the page: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html